# Limit exist means really what

Tags: calculus

Why there is need to use limit and what it really means. 
What is the relation between limit and derivatives

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

"Why do we use limits?"

The derivative is argument enough, really. Derivatives represent rates of change, and are hence used everywhere in engineering and science (particularly in the form of a differential equation). A derivative of $0$ means a stationary point, which is an important tool in simple optimisation problems.

"What is the relationship between derivatives and limits?"

Given a function $f$ that's defined at and around a point $x$, then the derivative $f'$ at $x$ is defined by,
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$
Geometrically, this is the gradient of the line between points $(x + h, f(x + h))$ and $(x, f(x))$, both on the graph of $f$. Such a line is called a secant. We take the limit of these gradients, as the points get closer together. When that limit exists, we have a derivative at the point, and the limiting gradient is the gradient of the tangent line.

"What do limits really mean?"

That's a tricky question. Often limits are introduced before the actual definition. The definition itself a lot for students to wrap their heads around, and is even trickier to apply! So, instead, we tend to opt for a more intuitive but less precise way of explaining them. If you want to know the full, precise definition, you can look up the epsilon-delta definition of a limit.

Essentially, the idea behind the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to some $a$ is to look at the function values "around" $a$ (but not at $a$) and determine a number which these points cluster around. If you look at $\frac{x^2 - 1}{x - 1}$, you can't substitute $x = 1$, since you'd be dividing by $0$. But, if you subbed in points around $x = 1$ (e.g. $x = 1.001, 0.999998$, etc), the function is defined, and you'd find that the function values are remarkably close to $2$. The closer you get, the closer to $2$ it becomes.

That's the idea of a limit, more or less: we look at the function value $f(x)$ for $x$ close to $a$. If they approach a single number (i.e. there's no asymptote or wild oscillation, or something like that), then that number is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$.

Comment: If   we  want answer at 1 then why we look for numbers which are close to one

Comment: In that case, it's because we can't get an answer at $1$. The same is true in the limit definition of the derivative: when $h = 0$, the expression is $\frac00$ which is undefined.